# NullPointerException when referring to val defined in subclass

Tags: scala

I have a case class that extends an abstract class. In its primary constructor, the superclass refers to an abstract value that is defined in the subclass.

```
abstract class SuperClass {
    def abstractValue: Seq[Int]

    val concreteValue: Int = {
        abstractValue.head
    }
}

case class SubClass() extends SuperClass {
    override val abstractValue: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3)
}
```

What I would expect is that creating an instance of `SubClass` would result in an object with `abstractValue = Seq(1,2,3)` and `concreteValue = 1`. However, creating an instance of `SubClass` throws a `NullPointerException`, because Scala tries to initialise `concreteValue` before `abstractValue`, which means that the latter is `null` when the former is initialised.

How do I make this work? Some things I've tried:

- Changing the declaration of `abstractValue` in `SubClass` from a `val` to a `def` solves the problem, but this has the unintended consequence of `abstractValue` being reinitialised every time it is referenced. This might be fine in the example, but not in the following cases:

  - The initialisation of `abstractValue` is expensive.
  - The initialisation of `abstractValue` is not repeatable (my use case).
- The same goes for changing the declaration of `concreteValue` in `SuperClass` from `val` to `def`.
- Changing the declaration of `abstractValue` in `SuperClass` from a `def` to a `val` does not solve the problem.
- It would probably be possible to solve this using `var` instead of `val`, but I like my case class instances immutable, thank you very much.

Comment: Looking at Related questions should give you much more explanation about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I have found that satisfies all restrictions mentioned in the question is changing the initialisation of `abstractValue` to a lazy one:

```
override lazy val abstractValue: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3)
```

This counterintuitively causes the initalisation of `abstractValue` to happen *earlier* than it would otherwise. Specifically, it happens "when it's needed", which is during the initialisation of `concreteValue`.

EDIT: As Shane Perry remarks in the comments, defining `concreteValue` as lazy (instead of `abstractValue`) also solves the problem. This approach is both more intuitive and more maintainable.

Comment: It may be more intuitive to define `concreteValue` as `lazy` which will cause the initialization of `concreteValue` to occur on first reference.  This has the added benefit that there won't be a requirement on the implementations to know that they must define `abstractValue` as lazy

Comment: I second that -- making concreteValue lazy works and more directly addresses the issue